# compiling / repairing monadiccp type errors

Tags: generics, haskell, types, typeerror

If anyone could help me look into this issue with compiling `monadiccp`, I'd appreciate it. There's a typing problem which I can't understand.

#### steps to reproduce

- have a reasonably up-to-date version of ghc installed; I have 7.0.3
- `cabal install Monatron`
- `cabal unpack monadiccp`
- `ghci Control/CP/ComposableTransformers.hs`

I get this error,

```
Control/CP/ComposableTransformers.hs:246:31:
    Couldn't match expected type `Tree solver0 a1 -> Tree solver0 a1'
                with actual type `forall a2. Tree solver a2 -> Tree solver a2'
    Expected type: Tree solver0 a1 -> Tree solver0 a1
      Actual type: Bound solver
    In the second argument of `BBP', namely `bound''
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `BBP (v + 1) bound''
Failed, modules loaded: Control.CP.Transformers, Control.CP.SearchTree, Control.CP.Solver, Control.CP.Queue, Control.CP.Debug, Control.CP.PriorityQueue, Control.Mixin.Mixin.
```

Here's an odd observation. If one changes the line in question,

```
   continue $ BBP (v + 1) bound'
```

to one which features the type given in the error,

```
   continue $ BBP (v + 1) (undefined :: Tree solver0 a1 -> Tree solver0 a1)
```

then it works, but if one introduces a dummy variable instead,

```
   let x = (undefined :: Tree solver0 a1 -> Tree solver0 a1)
   continue $ BBP (v + 1) x
```

the type errors become even more incomprehensible (I probably need to learn typing formally),

```
Control/CP/ComposableTransformers.hs:247:19:
    Couldn't match type `a10' with `a1'
      because type variable `a1' would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a type expected by the context: Tree solver a1 -> Tree solver a1
    The following variables have types that mention a10
      x :: Tree solver a10 -> Tree solver a10
        (bound at Control/CP/ComposableTransformers.hs:246:12)
    In the second argument of `BBP', namely `x'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `BBP (v + 1) x'
    In the expression: continue $ BBP (v + 1) x
```

any light shed on the situation would be most appreciated (including fixing the problem). I sent an email to the developer a while ago but he didn't get back.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what's going on, but simply manually rewriting the do-block got it to compile for me:

```
  returnCT (CBBST newBound) (BBP v bound) continue exit =
    newBound >>= continue . BBP (v + 1)
```

Comment: great, thanks very much! It looks like there are a number more errors though ... and this is a very odd problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could get `ComposableTransformers.hs` to compile by slightly uglifying some of the type definitions, as:

```
newtype CBranchBoundST solver a = CBBST (NewBound solver a)
data    BBEvalState solver a  = BBP Int (Bound solver a)

type Bound    solver a  = Tree solver a -> Tree solver a
type NewBound solver a  = solver (Bound solver a)

instance (Solver solver) => CTransformer (CBranchBoundST solver a)
where
  type CEvalState (CBranchBoundST solver a) = BBEvalState solver a
```

Basically, I've just threaded a type variable `a` through these definitions.  I'm reasonably sure the modified code means the same as the intent of the original.

Unfortunately, as the original question asker says, there are a bunch of other compilation errors that show up.